# Trap in database design

Tags: database, database-design

I need to design a database for somewhere. I have the following entities:
'food' -> foodId, foodName
'consumers'-> c_Id,cBreakfast,cLunch,cDinner
Consumers are eating three times. breakfast,lunch and dinner that these field take foods from 'food' entity with it's ID. 
But eventually I'd fall in the trap. I can not separate it into three meals breakfast, lunch and dinner do.
What design is more appropriate for this problem?

Comment: In my opinion it'll be better to create another table with day times like eat_time with fields id, name, and fill with 'breakfast', 'lunch' and 'dinner', and also create table which will union all tables like consumer_food_with_time and fields id, consumer_id, food_id, eat_time_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following schema would let you track who ate what and at which meal. In my example you can see that Bob had an omelet for breakfast, a salad for lunch and a steak for dinner. Mary missed breakfast, had a steak for lunch and a salad for dinner.

```
consumers
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(30)

+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Bob  |
|  2 | Mary |
| .. | .... |
+----+------+

consumptions
    id              unsigned int(P)
    consumer_id     unsigned int(F consumers.id)
    mealtime_id     unsigned int(F mealtimes.id)
    food_id         unsigned int(F foods.id)

+----+-------------+-------------+---------+
| id | consumer_id | mealtime_id | food_id |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 |           1 |           1 |       1 |
|  2 |           1 |           2 |       2 |
|  3 |           1 |           3 |       3 |
|  4 |           2 |           2 |       3 |
|  5 |           2 |           3 |       2 |
| .. | ........... | ........... | ....... |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------+

foods
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(20)

+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Omelet |
|  2 | Salad  |
|  3 | Steak  |
| .. | ...... |
+----+--------+

mealtimes
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(10)

+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Breakfast |
|  2 | Lunch     |
|  3 | Dinner    |
| .. | ......... |
+----+-----------+
```